# Use two taxonomy terms in one URL WP-API

Tags: wordpress, wp-api

At the moment I'm calling taxonomy term data using URL's like this -

```
http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/wp-json/posts?type=listings&filter[listing_area]=northwest
```

Is there a way I can call two taxonomy terms at the same time, something like this? -

```
http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/wp-json/posts?type=listings&filter[listing_area]=northwest&filter[listing_area]=northeast
```

I've read through all documentation but I'm struggling to find a solution, andy help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Changed comment to an answer - please see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the full code in place its hard to be 100% but try...

```
http://scd.blaze.wpengine.com/wp-json/posts?type=listings&filter[listing_area][]=northwest&filter[listing_area][]=northeast
```

By adding [ ] to the end of each reference to listing_area you are now passing through an array of values. Otherwise you just pass through the last value in the query string.

Comment: That is great to hear :) glad to be of help

Comment: Are you very experienced in using WP-API? I have a couple of issue's that if you wouldn't mind I'd like to get your opinion on?

Comment: Unfortunately not - its on my list for next year - I would suggest you head over to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ there should be some people there who can help :)

Comment: Ah well, worth a try! Thank you, I will do :)